# Regex in validate.js not working as expected

Tags: javascript, react-native, validate.js

I have the below rules and using validate.js but **regex does not seem to work**. Below is my code.

**Condition given** : Check if string has at least one capital letter, at least one symbol and at least one number

```
  password: {
    presence: {
      message: '^Please enter a password'
    },
    length: {
      minimum: 5,
      message: '^Your password must be at least 6 characters'
    },
    format: {
      pattern: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[\w~@#$%^&+=`|{}:;!.?\""()\[\]-]{1,}$/,
      message:
        '^Must contain a capital, lowercase, number and a special character!'
    }
  }
```

Comment: is the `length` & `presence` working ?

Comment: Please also add how do you use this validation in your code (code can be pasted here)